# Passing query-prameters in an API-request

Tags: python, python-requests, query-string

Why do I need to use a dictionary and set the parameters?
Such as `lat`, `lng` in following:

```
parameters = {
    "lat": MY_LAT,
    "lng": MY_LONG,
    "formatted": 0
}

response = requests.get(url="https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json", params=parameters)
```

Why can't I do the below, for instance to put in latitude?

```
response = requests.get(url="https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json", params=parameters, lat=MY_LAT)
```

Comment: because that's syntax

Comment: You almost can - in curly-braces like `params={'lat': MY_LAT}`. This way, the dictionary is defined _inline_ (as constant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass the arguments by name because the Python `requests` library doesn't know what parameters a given URL accepts. The API at sunrise-sunset.org takes `lat` and `lng` parameters, but most other APIs would have no use for them. By passing a dictionary of key=value pairs, you tell `requests` both the names and values of the parameters expected by the specific API you're calling.

Comment: "telling .. both the names and values of the parameters" that the designers of _requests_ could neither have foreseen, nor wanted to hard-code at design-time ️

Comment: @hc_dev I'm sure if we all pitched in, we could keep it up-to-date with all the parameters needed. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Your thoughts steer in the right direction, conceptually.

#### Passing query-parameters as arbitrary key-value pairs

Calling the `requests.get` method with arguments like `lat=MY_LAT` is exactly what the method needs. But the designer(s) of the *requests* library wanted to keep the method **generic**. That means, it should be suitable for all GET requests, no matter, what their query-parameters will be.

Hence, not knowing upfront, what the future query-parameters would be named, what type they require, or how many of them are needed, they couldn't have named and counted them fix.
The opposite was the case: The query-parameters should be flexible and sticking to the HTTP [query-string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) specification (RFC).
So, why not design one single parameter that holds this query-string, or its components as flexible key-value pairs ?!

#### A dictionary parameter like `kwargs` as multi-purpose bag

Whenever you like to design a method for an arbitrary number of parameters, you will craft a parameter like commonly-known [`kwargs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53676249/are-python-args-and-kwargs-ever-named-something-else-in-practice). This is actually a dictionary or map, that can hold as many and as manifold named parameters.

#### The parameter named `params` works pretty similar

Now, the parameter called `params` in `requests.get()` method is exactly that dictionary where you can put in as manifold key-value pairs.

In your case:

```py
parameters = {
    "lat": MY_LAT,
    "lng": MY_LONG,
    "formatted": 0
}
```

`parameters` as defined above is that dictionary or map. It can be used as catch-all single `param` to hold all the query-parameters with their arbitrary names and values. Just as currently required for the web-API or URL resource called.

#### You can wrap the call, explicitly using the coordinates

What you can do, especially in domain-driven design, wrap the GET call in your own method. For example:

```py
def get_sunrise_sunset_for(lat, lng):
    parameters = {
        "lat": lat,
        "lng": lng,
        "formatted": 0
    }
    response = requests.get(url="https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json", params=parameters)
    return response.json() # actually you would parse and return extracted times, etc.
```

There you designed it for a specific purpose (sunset/sunrise, instead of generic HTTP GET). So you can use parameters `lat` and `lng` explicitly. Furthermore you can return a specific response, like day-times.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is how the library you're using (requests) works. It's also how Python and almost every programming language handles method parameters.

Have you ever written a function like...

```py
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Notice how it's very clear what `a` and `b` are.

The same goes for the library you're using, requests. It doesn't know that the endpoint you are posting to has a `lat` parameter, how would it figure that out? How would you handle errors not knowing if parameters are correct or not?

If I were you, I'd read up on how parameters are handled in Python methods, and also on HTTP requests, and maybe that will help you see why they can't align.